# How to share internet from wifi of Raspberry pi through it's Ethernet port?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I want to share the internet coming from wifi to the RPi through it's ethernet port to a laptop (in this case a DVR) also the pi should act as a DHCP server. I found one helpful link:

[www.diyhobi.com/share-raspberry-pi-wifi-internet-ethernet/](https://www.diyhobi.com/share-raspberry-pi-wifi-internet-ethernet/)

but after completing some steps my entire wifi interface was gone and I have to put pi in the recovery mode.
So, I want a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around here and there, I found a simple solution to this problem, after following all the steps from 1 to 5 there is one extra step to be done

```
sudo dhcpcd
```

This is a very crucial step to restore all the network interfaces and of your system.
Then execute one of the major commands of linux

```
sudo apt-get update
```